# Scala Type Mismatch

Tags: scala, mongodb, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am having a problem with type mismatch.

type mismatch; found : Option[models.User] required: models.User

```
def authenticate = Action { implicit request =>
        signinForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
          formWithErrors => BadRequest(html.signin(formWithErrors)),
          user => Redirect(routes.Application.active).withSession(Security.username -> User.getUserName(user))
        )
      }
```

How can I force the function to accept Option[models.User] or can I convert the models.User into an Option?

The error occurs here: User.getUserName(user). getUserName requires models.User types.

===============================================

Update with all code used:

From User.scala

```
  def authenticate(email: String, password: String) : Option[User] = {
    (findByEmail(email)).filter { (user => BCrypt.checkpw(password, user.password)) }
  }

  def findByEmail(email: String) : Option[User] = {
    UserDAO.findOne(MongoDBObject("email" -> email))
  }
```

From Application.scala

```
  val signinForm = Form {
    mapping(
      "email" -> nonEmptyText, 
      "password" -> text)(User.authenticate)(_.map(user => (user.email, "")))
      .verifying("Invalid email or password", result => result.isDefined)
  }

  def authenticate = Action { implicit request =>
    signinForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => BadRequest(html.signin(formWithErrors)),
      user => Redirect(routes.Application.active).withSession(Security.username -> User.getUserName(user.get))
    )
  }
```

Comment: The real question here is why the success value of your form is an `Option[User]`—it doesn't make a lot of sense to say that you have a successful login form submission but no user. You may want to post a follow-up question with your `Form` definition.

Comment: I am pretty new to scala, and have been thinking about this. My rationale is that the `Form` definition should take an Option since signinForm makes use a user function `User.authenticate` that itself will spit out `Option[User]`. `User.authenicate` queries a mongo database via an email. If the email is not found, returns None which breaks the authentication, otherwise it will return `Some(User)`. Please correct me if I am wrong. I have edited my original post. @TravisBrown

Comment: It would be more natural to have the form not succeed if the authentication fails, and just to return a `User` if it doesn't—especially since your `verifying` clause means that you'll never get a `None`, anyway.

Comment: Thank you @TravisBrown, if I have any issues I will make a new post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To de-option an `Option[User]` into a `User`, you can do one of the following:

1)  The unsafe way.  Only do this if you are **sure** that `optUser` is not `None`.

```
val optUser: Option[User] = ...
val user: User = optUser.get
```

2)  The safe way

```
val optUser: Option[User] = ...
optUser match {
  case Some(user) => // do something with user
  case None => // do something to handle the absent user
}
```

3)  The monadic safe way

```
val optUser: Option[User] = ...
optUser.map(user => doSomething(user))
```

The biggest thing is that, if it's possible that `optUser` might actually be `None`, you need to figure out what you actually want to happen in the case that there is no `User` object.

There's a lot more information about `Option` in other StackOverflow questions if you'd like to read more.

Comment: Implemented, I am using User.getUserName(user.get) since I am sure it will never be none.