# Null safe way to deoption and avoid type mismatch

Tags: scala, option-type

While giving some readability advice [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/445681/131624) and checking that my rewrite hadn't broken anything, I discovered it was already broken.

```scala
case class Foo (
  bars: Seq[Bar]
)

case class Bar(s: String)

def findBarWithConditionals(foo: Foo, barToFind: String): Option[Bar] = {
   if (foo == null || foo.bars == null) {
     None
   } else {
     foo.bars.find(_.s == barToFind)
   }
}

def findBarWithOptions(foo: Foo, barToFind: String): Option[Bar] = {
   Option(foo).flatMap(f => Option(f.bars).map(_.find(_.s == barToFind)))
}
```

```
jdoodle.scala:16: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Option[this.Bar]
 required: this.Bar
   Option(foo).flatMap(f => Option(f.bars).map(_.find(_.s == barToFind)))
                                                     ^
```

I thought [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232095/scala-type-mismatch) might tell me how to fix it but I've had no luck with it.

Comment: as `_.find(_.s == barToFind))` will be an `Option[Bar]`, you will need a `flatMap` here as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `find` returns an `Option`, you want `flatMap` in both places, not a `flatMap` and a `map`.

```scala
Option(foo).flatMap(f => Option(f.bars).flatMap(_.find(_.s == barToFind)))
//                                      ^^^^^^^
//                            Note flatMap here
```

Comment: That made it happy. Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 1):

you are not far away of solve the problem. The complain from the compiler is in the `map` after `Option(f.bars)`. The quick fi would be

```scala
Option(foo).flatMap(f => Option(f.bars).flatMap(_.find(_.s == barToFind)))
```

but lets try to make it more readable

```scala
Option(foo)
  .flatMap(f => 
    Option(f.bars)
      .flatMap(_.find(_.s == barToFind))
  )
```

It could help, but scala offer [for-comprehensions](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/for-comprehensions.html). Which is a syntax sugar for `flatMap`, `map` and `withFilter`. Rewriting your code using this, it will look like the following

```scala
val nestedOptions = (for {
  f <- Option(foo)
  bar <- Option(f.bars)
} yield {
  // because of `bar.find` returns an `Option[Bar]`, the return type
  // of the for-comprehension will be `Option[Option[Bar]`
  bar.find(_.s == barToFind) 
})

// using `flatten` will fix that
nestedOptions.flatten 
// which is the same of using `flatMap` and apply the identity function 
nestedOptions.flatMap(x => x)
```

Your code and the one above would be the same once it is compiled. Another way of writing this, could be like the following

```scala
for {
  f <- Option(foo)
  bar <- Option(f.bars)
  barFound <- bar.find(_.s == barToFind)
} yield {
  barFound
}
```

Comment: I like the for-comprehension rewrites. But the "more readable" one still has fish gills and two calls on one line. I like it when errors with line numbers point right at the problem.

Comment: I like the same. It's easier to understand the error when the compiler says that you have a problem in some specific line and also column if it's possible. The error message you copyied, should have one more line with the symbol `^`, which is pointing to what was causing the issue.

Comment: Speaking of error messages, your last for-comprehension seems to work but the first one gives the same type mismatch as the map did.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not pointing out these issues to be chatty. I'm hoping for edits that would make me feel better about up voting.

Comment: lol. you are right. I wrote the code directly here instead of using an IDE or at least try to compile it. The issue is that `bar.find` returns an `Option`. what is inside the `for` block will be turned into `flatMap` and the `yield` block will be turned into `map`. Doing `bar.find(_.s == barToFind)` in the `yield` block will make the for-comprehension returns an `Option[Option[Bar]]`. In that case you could solve it using `flatten`. Let me edit it

Comment: that error is saying that `foo` is not declared in the scope. with only that message is not enough to know what is the root cause